# Firebird create database in specific directory

Tags: python, database, linux, ubuntu, firebird

I want to be able to create a firebird database in a specific directory. I know that the firebird user needs to have r/w/x permissions to the directory where I want to create the db. I created a group called 'tracker' and I added my user and the firebird user to that group.

```
firebird@ubuntu:/$ groups firebird
firebird tracker
```

I created a main directory called 'tracker'

```
drwxrwx---   3 me tracker  4096 Oct 16 10:40 tracker
```

Inside the 'tracker' directory I created an 'fdb' directory where I want the firebird DB's to be created.

```
drwxrwx--- 2 firebird firebird 4096 Oct 16 11:35 fdb
```

Now when I try to create the database using the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'localhost:/tracker/fdb/test.fdb' page_size 8192 user 'SYSDBA' password 'foobar' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

I get the following error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "open O_CREAT" operation for file "/tracker/fdb/test.fdb"
-Error while trying to create file
-Permission denied
```

If a change the 'tracker' directory to belong to the 'firebird' group then it creates the database, which makes sense, but since the firebird user belongs to the 'tracker' group, it shouldn't have any permission problems.

What am I missing here??

I'm using Ubuntu and firebird 2.5.

Thanks

Comment: Does the `firebird.conf` itself allow access to that location? Firebird can be configured to restrict access (using the `DatabaseAccess` configuration option).

Comment: It does. I did notice that I can get it to work if I change the permissions to this:

drwxrwx--x   3 me tracker  4096 Oct 16 10:40 tracker

Maybe there's another user (not firebird or me) trying to access this directory?

Comment: Is firebird running with supplementary group privileges?  My inference is that *tracker* is a supplementary group, and no the *firebird* user's primary group.  `grep ^Gid /proc/$FIREBIRD_PID/status` should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @pilcrow this is the result of that command:
Gid: 125 125 125 125
Which is the firebird gid
output of the id command for the firebird user:
uid=115(firebird) gid=125(firebird) groups=125(firebird),1001(fr-tracker)
'tracker' is a secondary group for the firebird user.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `grep -Ei 'groups|gid' /proc/$FBPID/status`.  We want to confirm that fb is running with the right supplementary groups.

Comment: @pilcrow here's the output of that command:
`Tgid: 973
Gid: 125 125 125 125
Groups: 125`
There should be a 1001(tracker GID)
`id command for the firebird user:
uid=115(firebird) gid=125(firebird) groups=125(firebird),1001(fr-tracker)`

Comment: Yes, that's your problem.  Suggest you migrate to serverfault, since this is now a question of invoking a daemon with the right supplementary groups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Linux often, but your comment that it does work if you add the execute bit for everyone on the higher level directory made me think again.

The Firebird server is running - presumably - under the *firebird* user. In your example setup this user had access to the `/tracker/fdb` folder, but no access to the `/tracker` folder.

To be able to access `/tracker/fdb` (eg to create a file), the user needs the eXecute permission on all higher level directories upto the root (otherwise the *firebird* user cannot know (or check) that the `fdb` folder even exists inside `/tracker`).

See also [Unix File Permissions](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/19060-unix-file-permissions.html):

> *What do r w and x really mean for a directory?*
>
> A directory is a file too, and "read" permission means you can read it. But you really cannot do very much without x permission as well. With directories, you usually have both read and execute permission or neither. On a directory, that x is officially called "search permission". You need x to use a directory in a pathname. So if you try "cat /etc/passwd", you will need x on / and /etc. You also need x to cd into a directory. Suppose you have read but not search (x) permission on a directory. What can you do? Not much. You can use "ls" to view the file names. Even "ls -l" will not work. Read access without search permission is not very useful. Still that is better than having only write permission on a directory...that is completely useless. I have not seen any other documentation that states this explicitly, so let me repeat it: write but no execute permission on a directory grants nothing at all.Suppose you have search (x) permission but no read permission on a directory. Now you can open files in the directory if you happen to know the file's name. You can cd into the directory. And that is it. You cannot even create a new file. Adding write permission will allow you to create files. And you can then delete files if you happen to know their name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. The tracker directory belongs to the 'tracker' group and the firebird user also belongs to the 'tracker' group. Doesn't that mean that as long as a directory has r/w/x permissions for the group, any member of that group has access to that directory ??

Comment: @jramirez I am not sure, but as adding 'x' for other fixed the problem I'd say user firebird is not part of the tracker group, or the firebird server is running under a different user account.

Comment: yes that's what I think too. but I tried 'su firebird' and navigating to the tracker directory, which I changed to only have 770 permissions and I was able to cd, mkdir and rm directories, which tells me that the firebird user does belong to the 'tracker' group. Maybe while creating the database there's another user that needs to have access to that directory other than the firebird user. I haven't been able to find any information that will corroborate the 'other user' theory. Thanks for the answer.